# How to proceed when the observed effect is smaller than the Minimum Detectable Effect?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, experiment-design, statistical-power, ab-test

Given an A/B test with an already defined sample size and variance, a power analysis was conducted to estimate the Minimum Detectable Effect (MDE) of a proportion.

After the experiment was concluded, the observed effect was smaller than the MDE. Should I calculate the p-value and confidence interval? Could it lead to misleading conclusions?

Comment: MDE = minimum detectable effect?

Comment: Please spell out MDE.  Many CV users are not native English speakers and acronyms can be particularly tricky.  I *am* a native speaker. I'm *guessing* @Dave is right but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, by MDE I mean the Minimum Detectable Effect, just edited the question.

Comment: CI and p-value will still be valid. Power analyses are just pre-test design guides.

Comment: You can still get lucky and get a stat-sig effect below the MDE where the ex-ante power is below 80% (or whatever threshold you used). Take a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538590/reconciling-the-minimum-detectable-effect-calculation-with-the-experiment-result) for an example.

Comment: [Probably not a duplicate, but related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595053/247274)